# Can you create a mathbuildup using IDWRITE?

Tags: winapi, com, rtf, directwrite, windowless

Is there already a built-in mechanism or method for creating a mathbuild using only the IDWRITE interfaces that would produce a similar type of math buildup compared to using an RTF window with the OLE/ITextRange2/ITextFont2 interfaces?

Comment: If you mean math expressions formatting, then no, there is nothing builtin for that in directwrite.

Comment: OK. So, I will have to figure out how to implement the Windowless TextService/TextHost to render the MathBuildUp to a device context instead of trying to scroll the MathBuildUp into view to do a screen capture from the RTF Edit window. I think this would be the easiest option rather than reinventing a MathBuildUp using D2D and DWRITE. If anyone has a more detailed example than what is found on MSDN of how to implement the Windowless TextService/TextHost interfaces, please share the knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

The Office riched20.dll supports window'd D2D/DWrite controls. See https://devblogs.microsoft.com/math-in-office/richeditd2d-window-controls/. The Windows 11 Notepad uses a window RichEdit control to get color emoji and other improvements available with the D2D/DWrite controls. With the msftedit.dll, you need to create a RichEdit windowless control to use D2D/DWrite. Reinventing MathBuildUp isn't easy unfortunately due to the effort to make UnicodeMath resemble a math notation. This introduces more complicated algorithms that look forward as well backward.

Comment: I came across two sample codes that would make me believe I can do this through the automation controls without diving into windowless code. The first example code https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/how-to-create-and-use-ccomptr-and-ccomqiptr-instances?view=msvc-170 shows how to open Word.Application via IDispatch and Invoke methods. The second sample example code https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/ is in VB and needs to be translated to c++. In the MS_Word>Math section, get a math object and perform a buildup from said object.